# retrieve loop comments of parent sql, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return the loop of all the comments where a comment is a comment-of an especific post.

For example in the next page `post?id=30` I want to show all the loop of comment till getting to the main post...does it makes sense?

**Posts**

```
id_post     |       post          | comment_of 
    25          main post               0 
    26          comment 1st level       25 
    27          comment 2nd level       26 
    28          another post            0 
    29          comment not related     14 
    30          comment 3rd level       27 
    31          comment not related     13
```

**Query**

```
    SELECT id_post, 
           post, 
           comment_of 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM posts 
    ORDER BY comment_of, id_post) posts_sorted, 
            (SELECT @pv := '25') initialisation 
    WHERE find_in_set(comment_of, @pv) 
    AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id_post)) /*key line*/
    OR id_post=@pv
```

**Result**

```
id_post     |       post          | comment_of 
    25          main post               0 
    26          comment 1st level       25 
    27          comment 2nd level       26 
    30          comment 3rd level       27
```

working fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c07667/2

**PROBLEM**

With this fiddle I go from the main post to the last comment....What I want is starting with the last comment `(id_post=30)` to get to the main post (id unknown) in page `post=?id=30`

Comment: "I want to get the results by the last comment, Not by the main post....in this case I want to get the same result by choosing 30 (last comment). Not vice versa" posting a expected result as ascii data table  says more then these words and also makes it more clear to understand.

Comment: I took the idea from @trincot [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) but he retrieves the results starting from the main post id...I want the opossite (starting from  the last_comment id)